# Swift - Type '(String, JSON)' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I'm using **SwiftyJSON**. Ultimately I want to see if the `"date"` value equals the value of `selectedDate` and if so, print the `"event"` value.

But I haven't even got that far yet. I'm getting an error on my `if` statement.

The error I'm receiving says `Type '(String, JSON)' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`.

data.json

```
[
 {
      "date": "01.01",
      "event": "Mom birthday",
     
  },
]
```

ViewController.swift

```
var json:JSON = false    
var selectedDate:String = "01.01"

func updateView() {
    
    json.forEach { (key, data) in
        if key == "date", data.stringValue == selectedDate {
            print("found it!")
        } else {
            print("no matches")
        }
    }
    
}
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

```
    // Get JSON data
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Devotions", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
            json = try JSON(data: data)
        } catch let error {
            print("parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
    
    updateView()
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify related line like:

```
data.forEach { (key, data) in
    if key == "date", data.stringValue == selectedDate {
        print("found it!")
    }
}
```

Or you can access directly like;

```
data["date"].stringValue == selectedDate
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I added an `else` statement and it's returning that result so I guess the `if` condition isn't being met. I'll update my code above with more details since they may be relevant.

Comment: The compilation error you specified should be fixed. Next step you can debug the json value `data` whether it contains "date" or not.